# Editar datos de DataTable con AlertDialog

Tags: python, flutter

Estoy haciendo un CRUD y quiero editar los datos del DataTable usando un AlertDialog pero solo consigo que me cargue el AlertDialog sin los datos, les dejo una imagen y el código
Espero pronta ayuda o sugerencias, gracias.
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

CARGA EL ALERTDIALOG SIN DATOS
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwQBo.png

CODIGO:

1.- DataTable

```
def main(page: ft.Page):

    codpro = TextField(label="CÓDIGO PRODUCTO")
    nompro = TextField(label="NOMBRE PRODUCTO")

    #combo de categoria
    ddcate = ft.Dropdown(label="CATEGORIA",
        width=150,
        options=[
            ft.dropdown.Option("dulce"),
            ft.dropdown.Option("salado"),
        ],
    )

    #combo de peso
    ddpeso = ft.Dropdown(label="PESO",
        width=100,
        options=[
            ft.dropdown.Option("KG"),
            ft.dropdown.Option("G"),
        ],
    )
   
    #DATATABLE
    tablaproducto = DataTable(
                  #CABECERA DE LAS CALUMNAS  
                  columns=[
                      DataColumn(Text("CÓDIGO")),
                      DataColumn(Text("PRODUCTO")),
                      DataColumn(Text("CATEGORÍA")),
                      DataColumn(Text("PESO")),
                      DataColumn(Text("ACCIONES")),
                  ],
                  #FILAS  
                  rows=[]          
    )
```

EDITAR

```
# Crear Dialog
    dialog = AlertDialog(
        title=Text("Editar datos"),
        content=Column([
            nompro,
            ddcate,
            ddpeso,
        ]),
        actions=[
            TextButton("Guardar",
                       on_click=guardar
                       )
        ]
    )


    #Funcion EDITAR
    def editar(e):

        tablaproducto.rows = nompro.value


        page.dialog = dialog
        dialog.open = True
        page.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude solucionar la edición de datos creando controles nuevos para que recuperar los datos del DataTable **pero solo me funciona con un registro, cuando agrego 2 o mas registros siempre me devuelve los datos del primer registro** les comparto el código, **alguna sugerencia de puedo solucionar el problema**

```
# CREANDO LOS CONTROLES PARA EDITAR DATOS
    edit_nomprotxt = TextField(label="NOMBRE PRODUCTO")

    edit_ddcate = ft.Dropdown(label="CATEGORIA",
        width=150,
        options=[
            ft.dropdown.Option("dulce"),
            ft.dropdown.Option("salado"),
        ],
    )

    edit_ddpeso = ft.Dropdown(label="PESO",
        width=100,
        options=[
            ft.dropdown.Option("KG"),
            ft.dropdown.Option("G"),
        ],
    )
```

ALERTA DIALOG

```
dialog = AlertDialog(
        title=Text("Editar datos"),
        content=Column([
            edit_nomprotxt,
            edit_ddcate,
            edit_ddpeso,
            
            
        ]),
        actions=[
            TextButton("Guardar",
                       on_click=guardar
                      )
        ]
    )
```

FUNCIÓN EDITAR

```
def editar(e):

        edit_nomprotxt.value = tablaproducto.rows[0].cells[1].content.value
        edit_ddcate.value = tablaproducto.rows[0].cells[2].content.value
        edit_ddpeso.value = tablaproducto.rows[0].cells[3].content.value


        page.dialog = dialog
        dialog.open = True
        page.update()
```